# Rails 7.0.2.2 thinks it's 7.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
MacOS Monterey
Ruby 3.1.0
npm v 8.4.1
yarn -v 1.22.17
```

There was no Rails on the system, and it had the system ruby installation.

I installed ruby through asdf. When I look into

```
~/..asdf/installs/ruby
```

I see:

```
 3.1.0
```

Then I did a rails 7.0.2.2 installation as follows:

```
gem install rails -v 7.0.2.2
```

It looked it went fine and the right gems were getting installed. The last statement was:

```
Successfully installed rails-7.0.2.2
```

Then I did the following:

```
 rails new myapp --database=mysql --skip-test --main --css=bootstrap
```

Watching the install, the following did not make sense:

```
Using activesupport 7.1.0.alpha from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at main@cece807)
Using activemodel 7.1.0.alpha from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at main@cece807)
Using actionview 7.1.0.alpha from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at main@cece807)
Using activejob 7.1.0.alpha from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at main@cece807)
Using activerecord 7.1.0.alpha from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at main@cece807)
Using actionpack 7.1.0.alpha from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at main@cece807)
Using activestorage 7.1.0.alpha from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at main@cece807)
Using railties 7.1.0.alpha from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at main@cece807)
Using actioncable 7.1.0.alpha from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at main@cece807)
Using actiontext 7.1.0.alpha from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at main@cece807)
Using actionmailbox 7.1.0.alpha from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at main@cece807)
Using actionmailer 7.1.0.alpha from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at main@cece807)
Using rails 7.1.0.alpha from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at main@cece807)

....

create  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_7_1.rb
....
remove  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_7_1.rb
```

Then when I opened up config/appliation.rb

I found this in it:

```
config.load_defaults 7.1
```

Any idea why this is happening? The rails 7.1.0(Alpha) does not even exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `rails new --help` will show that passing the `--main` flag will:

> Set up the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository main branch

And the [current version on Github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/RAILS_VERSION) is 7.1.0.alpha

If you want to use 7.0.2.2, just remove the `--main` flag